# Puppeteer Sharp export PDF Page break Cutting UI elements in to Half

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Puppeteer sharp is used for exporting web page in to PDF.
Its exporting PDF but while breaking the page its also cutting UI elements in to Half.
We require that it do page break but, UI element should be intact.

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same if you print the page to PDF?

Comment: @hardkoded yes, on print also page is UI element is breaking

Comment: So you need to change the page to be print-friendly.